# How to relase bitmap from a return method correctly?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapdata

Will this method will recycle the bitmap in `imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);`?.

because I can't put recycle after the `return methodBitmap;`

```java
Bitmap bitmap = imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);
//some process
...
//some process
bitmap.recycle();
```

## Update

After I'm done I put bitmap.recycle() but in `imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);` there's a bitmap inside that function, does it require to be recycle as well?

or

`bitmap.recycle()`   will automatically recycle the bitmap inside `imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);`?

```java
    public Bitmap mediaImageToBitmap(Image image, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        //Do I need to do bitmap recycle in this method's Java Class?
        //or 
        //The other class that call this method 
        //Bitmap bitmap = imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);
        //Then bitmap.recycle is enough?
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: After returning you are using the same bitmap ? If yes so you should not release it ..

Comment: you should release bitmap only after you are done with it and don't need it anymore. if you are done with bitmap before returning it. why are you even returning it

Comment: @ADM Yes, I still using it. After I'm done I put bitmap.recycle() but in ```imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);``` there's a bitmap, does it require to be recycle as well?

Comment: @A.easazadeh sorry for my poor english, please check the update. hope you can understand it better.

Comment: you have to always handle recycling bitmaps that you create yourself

Comment: @A.easazadeh please look on user10284284 explanation. If what he said is correct then I will give him a tick.

Comment: @Yao - yes what user10284284 says is true. i did not realize you didn't know that. that is just basic java. search about java reference type vs primitive types. this is a must know for java programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);` should only be returning reference to bitmap object which you assign to your local variable. In other words there is only one bitmap object and calling bitmap.recycle() once will automatically recycle that  bitmap object.

Comment: If a lot of people agree with your explanation. I will give you the tick.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement will not be executed after the return statement, but there is one block that block will execute after the return statement that is finally block with try catch if you know that concept:

```
public Bitmap methodBitmap() 
{
        Bitmap bitmap
        try {
            bitmap = imageUtils.mediaImageToBitmap(image, activity);
            //some process
        ...
            //some process

            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Do necessary step on exception case
            return bitmap;
        }
        finally {
            bitmap.recycle();    
        }
}
```

> Note : Take necessary argument on methodBitmap as per your need

Comment: Hi can you look at the recent update I make? Sorry for making you guys confuse

Comment: Catching `Exception` is almost _never_ a good idea.  It suppresses errors and makes reasoning about the program's state almost impossible.